# Custom motd.tcl does not show at startup

Tags: ssh, terminal, debian, welcome-file

I follow [this tutorial](http://www.mewbies.com/how_to_customize_your_console_login_message_tutorial.htm) in order to modify the ssh welcome message of my server, but when I ssh, I have no message at all...

Here is some informations:

**/etc/motd.tcl is executable**

```
➜  ~  ls -l /etc/motd.tcl 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3687 oct.  11 10:31 /etc/motd.tcl
```

**/etc/motd.tcl is at the end of  /etc/profile**

```
➜  ~  sudo cat /etc/profile | grep motd
/etc/motd.tcl
```

**/etc/motd.tcl displays my welcome message without any errors:**
[image: welcome message]

**My /etc/ssh/sshd_config contains the following lines:**

```
PrintMotd yes
PrintLastLog no
```

Maybe the tutorial is outdated and I have to change something but I did not manage to find the information.

Thanks for any hints.

**Edit:** Issue seems to be due to zsh/oh-my-zsh because when I log in with the root account (which does not have zsh shell) the motd is displayed

Comment: If you need just non-variable MOTD, you should name the file as `/etc/motd` (without the tcl) extension.

Comment: I have variables but this is an exemple

Comment: Does your system use `systemd` or you use old `init` scripts? Preferred way is to use pam_motd` if you need to modify `motd` for login.
Anyway if you consider you found the solution, answer the question and do not edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, there's this section:

```
# * Check if we're somewhere in /home
#if {![string match -nocase "/home*" $var(path)]} {
if {![string match -nocase "/home*" $var(path)] && ![string match -nocase "/usr/home*" $var(path)] } {
  return 0
}
```

I've verified with a `puts` before `return 0` that when I log in and the MOTD would be shown, this `if` gets executed, preventing the rest of the script from outputting anything. Remove these lines and it should work as expected.